# Can I speed up INSERT IGNORE on large row counts

Tags: mysql

I'm importing a huge number of rows into a table, INSERT IGNORE is decreasing in speed as it checks the primary value before execution. Can anyone offer insight into how or even if I can tune the process to maintain speed. There will be millions of rows by the end of the import i expect.

I read some arbitrary git project that mentioned "insert_no_overwrite" which it claims would speed up import as it supposedly doesn't query the whole primary column just prints and if the value matches another ignores it and moves on.

any insight would be appreciated, there are similar question on here but not identical that i could find.

Comment: What are you importing, csv, from another table import sql statenentö... depending what you do you can look for bulk insert, i thinl everything is here or at dba discussed

Comment: the values are imported one by one, so no bulk or csv file. I'm kind of expecting there to be no alternative, I was hoping that some expert may have a suggestion that i wouldn't know about but it's a long shot

Comment: as i still don't know the base of that data, is,m there is nothing to tell. I would you refer to dba, but without vital informatiom they also can't help